# SSM document approach to implement SQL Server (in RDS) user password rotation

Tags: aws-secrets-manager, aws-ssm

Providing the backgroud of the existing application setup so that it is clear why I'm trying to do something what I'm trying to do
Have gone through the AWS documentation and already reviewed the details in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/reference_available-rotation-templates.html

Among the options provided, this template suits the scenario https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-secrets-manager-rotation-lambdas/blob/master/SecretsManagerRDSSQLServerRotationSingleUser/lambda_function.py
provides the code to rotate the secret in secrets manager and update the sql user in database.
In this approach, I could see that lambda function needs permission to change the secret and also connect to RDS database and EXECUTE LOGIN/USER script.

The application consumes secrets from single json secret that has below structure so that .Net application can overlay this secret on the json. This also minimizes the number of secreat reads based on consolidation

```json
{
  "OktaConfiguration": {
    "clientSecret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "SQLConnectionStrings": {
    "Pwd": "ppppppppppppppppppppp",
  },
  "ExternalAPI_ABC": {
    "clientSecret": "sssssssssss",
  }
}
```

So now that I have to implement rotation and as based on understanding of AWS secret manager using secret versioning during update, I'm trying to break this down as 2 step process

- Step-1 - Establish a separate secret for each of the application secret and use lambda rotation function that just rotates the secret manager secret without worrying who is the consumer of this secret using AWS::SecretsManager::RotationSchedule. So all it does is update the value of secret to a newly generated value as described in lambda
- Step-2 - Create SSM document that has read-only access to the secret in step-1 and update the underlying service's secret value following appropriate method (for example if it ia DB connection running ALTER LOGIN.USER script on the DB) and then if it is successful, update the corresponding key's value in consolidated json secret taking advantage of ability to jump to different actions (multiple steps provided by SSM document)

Step-1 is achieved easily.
The step-2 is easier for Windows accounts secrets as I could write SSM documents to execute PowerShell scripts that run in the context of EC2 instance associated with that account.
However I could not find any good reference on executing SQL scripts to be executed on RDS DB without relying on EC2 instance? Worried if I'm going down a rabbit hole with this approach.

Any quick pointers and directions is much appreciated.

Comment: **Quick update**
Went down the path of updating the json secret (the key SQLConnectionStrings:Pwd) from the DB user secret rotation lambda upon successful DB update. If there are any other pointers/directions to achieve my original approach, would refactor at later point.